# tabBarController delegate didn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I use below delegate method to set the tabBarController not to pop to another sub view controller by setting the return value to NO,

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    UIViewController *vc =[((UINavigationController *)viewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"LYAppCategoryViewController")]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"" otherButtonTitles:@"", nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;

    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

but after "NO" was actually returned,the `tabBarController` still pop to another `sub view controller`. So it's kinda puzzling，am I getting it wrong, the scenario of using it?

quotes from Apple API "`YES` if the `view controller’s` tab should be selected or `NO` if the current tab should remain active."

thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Can you give the code you put in the method ?

Comment: If you use a storyboard, did you make sure you set your UITabBarController's class to your subclass ? Is your method called (you can check with a simple NSLog) ?

Comment: I just edited the question,please take your time to check it,thanks.

Comment: I wrote this code in the view controller(vc),vc->navigationController->tabBarController,and I find navigationController by the "view controller" in this method.

Comment: Are you sure your code is going in the "if" part and not the else ?

Comment: Also, you have an empty UIAlertView which is kind of weird..

Comment: AlertView thing is not the problem as I see, also I did debug and saw program stepping into the "if" part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48466/discussion-between-piachai-and-rdurand)

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't get the reason why this happened,but I accomplished my target by adding codes like this:

```
        [tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]];
        [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

tabBarController will not pop to another view controller if "forcing" to pop to the first one.